# WiFi - slow download, fast upload. Affects only one device

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-speed

My desktop computer is getting terrible download speeds, while other devices work just fine on the same network. Here are speedtest.net results from my devices, Mbps:

- Nexus 4: 24.9 down / 26.8 up
- MacBook: 31.3 down / 28.5 up
- Desktop: **6.6 down** / 28.2 up

All three devices connect to the same network (also tested in the same physical location), hitting the same remote server. Results stay fairly consistent between runs.

The desktop PC uses a TP Link TL-WN881ND PCI-e wifi card and runs Windows 8 (identifies as 'Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter'), default drivers, no additional wifi-related software installed.

My router is a TP Link TL-WR841N, default firmware. I have tried disabling WMM, changing router mode / channel width - none of those improved download speeds on the desktop.

Also, tried using my phone as a wifi hotspot and got the following results:

- MacBook: 10.0 down / 1.6 up
- Desktop: 9.0 down / 1.6 up

Much closer this time - problems with the specific wifi card / router combination?

Edit: I 'fixed' my issue by switching WiFi card to a TP Link TL-WDN4800. However, I still do not know what caused the original problem.

Comment: If you hard wire the desktop, does the download speed change?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run cables to the desktop. It does go up when connected to another wifi (phone in hotspot mode), but that goes through another provider.

Comment: Are you able to test a 'dongle' or a different wifi card?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to fix the issue, whatever it was.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it's your card. Try a different card or a wireless dongle.